# How do I prevent Visual Studio Code from breaking long lines when formatting code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using the latest Visual Studio Code with Prettier code formatting plugin. The problem is, it breaks long statements like this:

```
var text = Ext.String.format(gettext("{0} used of {1}"), local_used, local_quota);
```

Into this:

```
var text = Ext.String.format(
  gettext("{0} used of {1}"),
  local_used,
  local_quota
);
```

Is there a way to disable this setting?

Comment: The problem is not VSCode, it's prettier.  Either change your settings or just drop prettier if you don't think it's helpful.  https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Comment: As far as I know, the only way is to let Prettier ignore it by using a Javascript comment of `// prettier-ignore`. It only ignores the following node of code. https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there's no way of doing this globally. Since I only need this plugin for Javascript, I switched to Beautify altogether and changed the default formatter from Prettier to Beautify with a right click -> "Format Document With" -> "Configure Default Formatter...".

The Beautify plugin seems to keep single line statements as they are.

Comment: "The Beautify plugin seems to keep single line statements as they are." Not anymore. I'm trying to find a way to stop this in Beautify...